# Generating a data frame of all Twitter followers and their location Using TwitteR

Tags: r, twitter, dataframe

I'm new to the twitter package and am trying to geterate a data frame which 
is comprised of users who follow me, their location, and number of tweets.

```
name    location       tweets
sfih    Denver, CO     100 
oiho    Italy          503
seih    Space          205
soei    Hell           1
```

After reading the twitteR documentation, I saw that there are various methods for 
getting the user name of followers and getting individual tweets from them. (getUser, 
getName, etc) I'm wondering if there is a quick single line command to 
get all users that follow me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, from the twitteR documentation it can be seen that you can easily call those methods for given user. E.g.:

```
> getUser('daroczig')$getFollowers()
[[1]]
[1] "ThankToHouseUS"

[[2]]
[1] "RCommunity"

[[3]]
[1] "gnome_tips"
```

---

**Update**: and based on the above you could also easily fetch all required information from all `user` classes with a one-liner, eg.:

```
> t(sapply(getUser('daroczig')$getFollowers(), function(x) c(x$name, x$location, x$statusesCount)))
     [,1]                [,2]                  [,3]  
[1,] "Thank To House US" "Dallas, TX"          "47"  
[2,] "R Community"       "Surabaya, Indonesia" "64"  
[3,] "Rodrick Jacquez"   ""                    "1326"
```